# Share date time between PHP and C# using Neo4j, Neo4jPHP and Neo4jClient

Tags: c#, php, datetime, neo4jclient, neo4jphp

I'm writing a data import script for gathering some data with dates from PHP and I'm writing the results to Neo4j using Neo4jPHP. However, I'm not sure how to get a date time object in PHP to be represented as a serialized `DateTimeOffset` that can be read through Neo4jClient on the C#.NET side.

When serializing a DateTimeOffset using Neo4jClient in C#.NET, its internal format in Neo4j looks like this:
`"2013-07-12T13:06:44.3940861+00:00"`

According to the documentation on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx, the above date time string can be broken into these pieces:
`"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.FFFFFFFzzz"`

I see that the PHP date() function doesn't support microseconds, but DateTime::format() does. I'm not an expert in PHP so I'm not sure the best method for approaching the conversion. I'm not simply looking for a PHP full Date/Time because the C# DateTimeOffset supports microseconds. How would I achieve the above date format in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php dates is based on timestamp, it counts the seconds from 1/1/1970

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php

http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.time.php

you can use this "Y-m-d H:i:s.u"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I slightly modified the format string to include the escaped T. `$dt = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP', $epoch);`